# Applying $(this) to the main selector from a child selector?

Tags: javascript

How do I use a `$(this)` from the main selector form a child selector? I'm creating this for a highlighting program. On click of `#red_box`, you can change the color of the original highlight (`.green_mark`).

**The Problem**

I'm using `$(this)` to apply to `.green_mark` and not to `#red_box`.

**What I've Tried**

I've tried adding a variable inside of the mouse over function, but before the red_box click function:

```
var green_this = $(this);
```

I would then use `green_this` inside of the red_box click function. The problem, it changes *all* of the `.green_mark's`. I only want to change this *particular* .green_mark.

**How can I solve this?**

My Code:

```
$(".green_mark").mouseover(function() {
     $("#red_box").click(function() {
          $(this).attr("class","red_mark");
});
});
```

### EDIT

When you *mouseover* `.green_mark`, a div appears, that *contains* `#red_box`. Why is this? This div allows you to change the color of your current highlight? I need to use `$(this)` to only direct this only type of highlight and not all instances of the same color. **.green_mark and #red_box have no parent/child relationship. Their only relationship is in the select statement.**

### EDIT 2

I keep getting requests for the HTML. I have resisted because it will only make this problem more complicated. But here is the HTML:

**NOTE:** The SO Editor is messing up the effect for the offset for the `.green_mark`.

```js
$(".green_mark").mouseover(function() {
    var offsets = $(this).offset();
    var top = offsets.top;
    var new_top = top - 10;
    var left = offsets.left;
    var new_left = left - 10;
    $('#change_color').css({
  'top':new_top+'px',
  'left':new_left+'px'
    });
  
  $("#blue_box2").click(function() {
    alert("This selector here");
    });
  
 });
```

```css
#change_color { 
position:absolute;
    border:grey solid 1px;
    background: #373737;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none;   /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
  -khtml-user-select: none;    /* Konqueror */
  -moz-user-select: none;      /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;       /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
  user-select: none;           /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  not supported by any browser */
  }

.blue_mark {
  background: #AAF6FF;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.red_mark {
  background: #FF9B9F;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.green_mark {
  background: #D6FFAA;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.yellow_mark {
  background: #FFF8AA;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.orange_mark {
  background: #FFBF98;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.purple_mark {
  background: #D7D5FC;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.boxes, .boxes2 {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
}

#blue_box2 {
  background: #AAF6FF;
}

#green_box2 {
  background: #D6FFAA;
}

#orange_box2 {
  background: #FFBF98;
}

#purple_box2 {
  background: #D7D5FC;
}

#red_box2 {
  background: #FF9B9F;
}

#yellow_box2 {
  background: #FFF8AA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='actual_verse' class='context'>Lore<span class="orange_mark">m ipsum dolor sit amet, iisque scripserit nec at, an case ponderum mea, delectus volupt</span>aria in quo. Te aliquid ce<span class="red_mark">teros legendos has. Veritus assueverit intelleg</span>eba<span class="orange_mark">t id per</span>, eos cu vero pri<span class="green_mark">mis philo</span>sophia, no nec blandit propriae<span class="green_mark">. Mei stet ferri aperiri eu. Mucius deserunt sensibus eum id.

Ut cas</span>e nominavi pro, <span class="yellow_mark">dico reprimique suscipiantur in per. Cu vocibus ceteros sententiae mel. Nam te diam ornatus, mei sonet volutpat facilisis ut. Minim mazim persequeri</span>s sed id, mei et animal equidem, clita atomorum at has. <span class="green_mark">Ut noluisse placerat suscipiantur mel</span>, cu pri mundi dicunt <span class="green_mark">praesent. Ignota dicunt vulputate ad vim, </span>populo option aperiri <span class="orange_mark">me</span><span class="purple_mark">l in. Has cu essent eirmod malorum, nisl electram pri et.

In legimus posidonium his, aeque possit platonem vel ne, nam ad meis nemore delenit. Cu discere legimus eam. Eum eius nostro ad, pro solet semper per</span><span class="orange_mark">fe</span>cto ne, et eros dicam tantas pro. Ex malorum debitis cotidieque pro. Vel in legendos elaboraret conclusionemque, mutat moderatius cotidieque cu usu, mel copiosae assueverit ne. Odio imperdiet eos in, cum sint porro splendide ne, tritani aliquam eum ne.

Mel feugiat recusabo platonem ei, sea cu numquam constituam. Ne tempor postea vim. Ad volumus accumsan apeirian has. At ius aliquid convenire, id est aliquip vivendo accusam.

Solum scaevola ius ut, cum no mutat sadipscing. Mei te dico dolor scaevola, cu veri dictas sit, an per nullam oblique. Ex sit sale quidam reprehendunt, diam velit lucilius nam ne, mnesarchum efficiendi his ut. Nec vivendo mediocrem delicatissimi id, ad debet maiorum qui. No qui latine dolorum corpora, diam cetero insolens in cum.</span>

<div id='change_color'>
  <div id='blue_box2' class='boxes2' title='Blue'></div>
  <div id='green_box2' class='boxes2' title='Green'></div>
  <div id='yellow_box2' class='boxes2' title='Yellow'></div>
  <div id='orange_box2' class='boxes2' title='Orange'></div>
  <div id='purple_box2' class='boxes2' title='Purple'></div>
  <div id='red_box2' class='boxes2' title='Red'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The logic seems to be confusing. When you are `mouseover` -ing a dom element how it is possible to `click` another element

Comment: Show your html code plz

Comment: This is never going to be good to add a `.click()` handler on every single `.mouseover()` event.  You will end up with zillions of identical click handlers.  Please back up a few steps, show us your HTML and explain what problem you're trying to solve.  This question is entirely an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you've described some issue with a flawed attempt at a solution rather than describing the actual problem so we can help you find a good solution to it.  You need to start over with a fresh approach.

Comment: Let me explain, when you mouse over `.green_mark`, a div appears that _contains_ `#red_box`. This being said, `.green_mark` and `#red_box` have no real connection to each other...

Comment: Please see edit

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the class of the parent `.green_mark`:

```
$(".green_mark").mouseover(function() {
     $("#red_box").click(function() {
          $(this).parent('.green_mark').attr("class","red_mark");
     });
});
```

This would be a better way to code it though (by removing the outer `mouseover` part):

```
$("#red_box").click(function() {
    $(this).parent('.green_mark').attr("class","red_mark");
});
```

Comment: Please see edit. `.green_mark` and `#red_box` have no parent child relationship.